Not able to setup SimpleLoggerAdvisor within a ChatClient in Spring AI
I'm new  Spring AI. I was able to setup a chat client successfully with the following setup:
@Bean
fun chatClient(builder: ChatClient.Builder, vectorStore: VectorStore): ChatClient = builder
   .defaultAdvisors(
      QuestionAnswerAdvisor(vectorStore, SearchRequest.defaults())
   )
   .build()

The chat client is then used in the following manner within the service:
   val prompt = promptService.createPrompt(userQuery, userType)
   val response = chatClient.prompt(prompt).call()

Now I'm trying to use logging using similarly as described in the documentation with the following change:
@Bean
fun chatClient(builder: ChatClient.Builder, vectorStore: VectorStore): ChatClient = builder
   .defaultAdvisors(
      QuestionAnswerAdvisor(vectorStore, SearchRequest.defaults())
      SimpleLoggerAdvisor()
   )
   .build()

And adding the logging level for the advisor package to DEBUG in my config:
logging.level:
  org.springframework.ai.chat.client.advisor: DEBUG

But I cannot see any debug logs. What am I missing here?
I tried to run a query and I was expecting to see some debug logs, but there are no logs in the console.

I'm doing the below using Spring AI 1.0.0-M2 and have no issue.
@Bean
    ChatClient vectorStoreChatClient(ChatClient.Builder builder , VectorStore vectorStore) {
        return builder
                .defaultAdvisors(
                        new QuestionAnswerAdvisor(vectorStore, SearchRequest.defaults()),
                        new SimpleLoggerAdvisor())
                .build();
    }

